# Apk packaging failed : opencv header files not found

Tags: android, opencv, unreal-engine4, packaging

I am trying to package an apk of my project (with Android ASTC) on Unreal Engine 4. Note that I added a plugin for the OpenCV 3.2 library in my project.

When I open my project with Visual Studio 2019 and build it, it works with no error and opens the project in Unreal Engine just fine(meaning that there is no problem with finding opencv2 files/paths). Also, when I click "Play", it works because I can use opencv features.

However, when I try to package the project into an apk with Android ASTC, it fails.

Would you have any idea on how to solve that ?

Here is the logs :

```
LogUObjectHash: Compacting FUObjectHashTables data took   0.81ms
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Running AutomationTool...
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Parsing command line: -ScriptsForProject="C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/MyProject.uproject" BuildCookRun -nocompileeditor -nop4 -project="C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/MyProject.uproject" -cook -stage -archive -archivedirectory="C:/Users/mkarada
g/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/apk" -package -ue4exe=E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Cmd.exe -ddc=DerivedDataBackendGraph -pak -prereqs -nodebuginfo -targetplatform=Android -cookflavor=ASTC -build -CrashReporter -target=MyProject -clientconfig=Development -utf8output -compile
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Dependencies are up to date (0,291s). Skipping compile.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Setting up ProjectParams for C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth\MyProject.uproject
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ********** BUILD COMMAND STARTED **********
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Running: E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe UnrealPak Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth\MyProject.uproject"  "C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth\MyProject.uproject" -NoUBTMakefile
s  -Manifest=E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml -NoHotReload -log="E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBT-UnrealPak-Win64-Development.txt"
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth).
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Writing manifest to E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Target is up to date
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Total execution time: 1,79 seconds
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Took 1,9507473s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=0
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Running: E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe MyProject Android Development -Project="C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth\MyProject.uproject"  "C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth\MyProject.uproject" -NoUBTMakefi
les  -remoteini="C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth" -skipdeploy -Manifest=E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml -NoHotReload -log="E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBT-MyProject-Android-Development.txt"
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (C:\Users\mmm\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject - MergeXRAuth).
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Android dedicated server is made to depend on OpenCV. We want to avoid this, please correct module dependencies.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   PLATFORM_ANDROID_NDK_VERSION = 210500
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   NDK toolchain: r21e, NDK version: 21, GccVersion: 4.9, ClangVersion: 9.0.9
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Compiling Native 64-bit code with NDK API 'android-21'
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Writing manifest to E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Building MyProject...
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   Building 6 actions with 16 processes...
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     [1/6] Module.OpenCV.cpp [arm64]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     In file included from C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Intermediate/Build/Android/MyProject/Development/OpenCV/Module.OpenCV.cpp:3:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     In file included from C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Plugins/OpenCV/Source/OpenCV/Private/WebcamReader.cpp:4:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Plugins/OpenCV/Source/OpenCV/Public\WebcamReader.h(5,10): fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     1 error generated.
PackagingResults: Error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     [2/6] Module.OpenCV.gen.cpp [arm64]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     In file included from C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Intermediate/Build/Android/MyProject/Development/OpenCV/Module.OpenCV.gen.cpp:3:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     In file included from C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Intermediate/Build/Android/MyProject/Inc/OpenCV/WebcamReader.gen.cpp:8:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Plugins/OpenCV/Source\OpenCV/Public/WebcamReader.h(5,10): fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     1 error generated.
PackagingResults: Error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     [3/6] MyActor_Pretreating.cpp [arm64]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     In file included from C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Source/MyProject/MyActor_Pretreating.cpp:4:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Source/MyProject/MyActor_Pretreating.h(10,10): fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     1 error generated.
PackagingResults: Error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     [4/6] MyActor_Pretreating.gen.cpp [arm64]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     In file included from C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Intermediate/Build/Android/MyProject/Inc/MyProject/MyActor_Pretreating.gen.cpp:8:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     C:/Users/mmm/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject - MergeXRAuth/Source\MyProject/MyActor_Pretreating.h(10,10): fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):     1 error generated.
PackagingResults: Error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Took 10,8987303s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=6
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (E:\UnrealEngine-4.27\UnrealEngine-4.27\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBT-MyProject-Android-Development.txt)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

Comment: please do not post *images* of errors, but TEXT, thank you.

Comment: why did you tag this as opencv **3.2**? is the issue only reproducible with that specific version? -- please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.